# Error while getting array of object from axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api, axios

I am passing an array of object (hardcode values) to make a get request with axios but every time getting error like this:

[image]

Need assistance in this, I'm new to react js. In my opinion I'm making mistake in making the array of object or I think we can't pass an const to the axios?

**function and array of object (hardcode value)**

```
const api =
    [
        {
            "description": "",
            "durationday": "fullday",
            "end": "null",
            "id": 0,
            "location": "",
            "start": "null",
            "title": "",
        },
        {
            "description": "yaaa!",
            "durationday": "absent",
            "end": "10-04-2021 12:10:00",
            "id": 1,
            "location": "perth",
            "start": "10-04-2021 12:10:00",
            "title": "holiday",
        },
        {
            "description": "busy",
            "durationday": "fullday",
            "end": "10-22-2021 12:10:00",
            "id": 2,
            "location": "melbourne",
            "start": '10-19-2021 12:00:00',
            "title": "working",
        },
        {
            "description": "dd",
            "durationday": "halfday",
            "end": "10-24-2021 12:10:00",
            "id": 3,
            "location": "updated perth",
            "start": "10-24-2021 12:10:00",
            "title": "updated holiday",
        }
    ]



console.log(api)


const getEvents = () => {
    axios.get(api)
        .then(response => {

            console.log(response.data)

        })

    .catch(err => console.log("This is error for fetching", err))
   

}
useEffect(() => {
    getEvents()
}, []);
```

Comment: Its a GET request, to follow API REST Rules you should use this to retrieve resources, so you should not be passing a body. To do so, you can do it as a POST request to submit new data to the server. You may find this useful: https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/

Comment: The first argument to axios.get is a url, but you’re passing an array of objects. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things here to make API REST request:

1- Its a GET request, to follow API REST Rules you should use GET to retrieve resources, so you should not be passing a body.

2- The first param you have to use when making an api request is the url endpoint as a string for example: axios.get(“/endpointPath”).then….

3- To send all that data to the server, you can do it as a POST request to submit new data. For example: axios.post(“/endpointPath”,body).then… in this case the body could be your api const(you dont need to pass it as json if you are not using postman or another client)

4- You may find this useful: https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/